# Python unicode translation leaves input unchanged

Tags: python, unicode, arabic, transliteration, farsi

I have written a python code that is supposed to translate/transliterate Persian characters. Here is a chunk of the translation table:

```
dictionary = {
'\u062B': 's̱',
'\u062C': 'ǧ',
}
```

'\u062B' is "ث" which should be translated to "s̱"

but when I run the following:

```
string = ('\u062B')
print("Original string:", string)

string = ('\u062B')
print("Translated string:", string.translate(dictionary))
```

My original string and Translated string are the same:

```
Original string: ث
Translated string: ث
```

So the translation doesn't occur. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`str.translate` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) table maps from unicode *ordinals* (i.e. integers) to ordinals, strings, or None. Use [`str.maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.maketrans) to convert the string-to-string mapping appropriately:

```py
>>> string
'ث'
>>> str.maketrans(dictionary)
{1579: 's̱', 1580: 'ǧ'}
>>> string.translate(str.maketrans(dictionary))
's̱'
```